# Javascript поиск дубликатов с исключением

Tags: javascript, if

У меня имеются след. переменные :

```
var a2 = 3;
var b2 = 10;
var c2 = 3;
var d2 = 3;
var e2 = 10;

var wild =10;
```

Задача пройтись по порядку от a2 до e2 в поиске дубликатов , и вызывать функцию console.log(); при
совпадении каждой комбинаций (a2,b2,c3) , (a2,b2,c3,d2) , (a2,b2,c3,d2,e2)
проверку должны пройти комбинации с одинаковыми значениями от начала до конца:

```
true, если значение по прядку совпадают :
если :
a2=0,b2=0,c2=0
вызвать функцию 1
если :
a2=0,b2=0,c2=0,d2=0
вызвать функцию 2
если :
a2=0,b2=0,c2=0,d2=0,e2=0
вызвать функцию 3

false , если значение одного из элементов отличается от ряда дубликатов .
например :
a2=1,b2=0,c2=0
a2=0,b2=1,c2=0,d2=0
a2=0,b2=0,c2=1,d2=0,e2=0
```

Но главная задача является добавить исключение , а именно переменную wild которая = 10.

```
например такой ряд комбинации считается true:
a2=10,b2=0,c2=0
a2=0,b2=10,c2=0,d2=0
a2=0,b2=0,c2=10,d2=0,e2=0
```

Без данного исключения (wild) поиск и сравнение можно было бы реализовать данным образом

```
//Проверка дубликатов
if(a2==b2){
console.log("a2==b2");
if(b2==c2){
console.log("b2==c2");
if(c2==d2){
console.log("c2==d2");
if(d2==e2){
console.log("d2==e2");
}
}
}
}
```

Подскажите как в данную конфигурацию добавить wild как исключение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так подходит?

```js
function test(wild, a2, b2, c2, d2, e2) {
  var firstNotWild = [a2, b2, c2, d2, e2].find(num => num !== wild);
  var valid = new Set([wild, firstNotWild ?? wild]);

  if(valid.has(a2) && valid.has(b2)) {
    console.log("a2==b2");
    if(valid.has(c2)) {
      console.log("b2==c2");
      if(valid.has(d2)) {
        console.log("c2==d2");
        if(valid.has(e2)) {
          console.log("d2==e2");
          console.log("All match.");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

test(10, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
test(10, 3, 10, 3, 3, 10)
test(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)
test(10, 3, 10, 3, 0, 10)
```

Вариант 2:

```js
test(10, { a1: 3, b1: 3, c1: 3, d1: 3, e1: 3 });
test(10, { a2: 3, b2: 10, c2: 3, d2: 3, e2: 10 });
test(10, { a3: 10, b3: 10, c3: 10, d3: 10, e3: 10 });
test(10, { a4: 3, b4: 10, c4: 3, d4: 0, e4: 10 });

// Функцию также легко вызывать с переменными:

const a5 = 3;
const b5 = 10;
const c5 = 3;
const d5 = 3;
const e5 = 10;

test(10, { a5, b5, c5, d5, e5 });

function test(wild, numbers) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(numbers));

  const keys = Object.keys(numbers);
  const values = Object.values(numbers);

  const firstNotWild = values.find(num => num !== wild);
  const valid = new Set([wild, firstNotWild ?? wild]);

  for (let i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++) {
    if (valid.has(values[i]) && valid.has(values[i + 1])) {
      console.log(`${keys[i]}==${keys[i + 1]}`);
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста , а как прогнать эту функцию несколько раз но с разными console.log , например сначала прошли по выборке :
a2, b2, c2, d2, e2
console.log("a2==b2");
console.log("b2==c2");
console.log("c2==d2");
console.log("d2==e2");
затем я  хочу запустить такую же функцию но с другими входными через setTimeout 2 сек :
a2, b2, c2, d2, e2
console.log("a1==b1");
console.log("b1==c1");
console.log("c1==d1");
console.log("d1==e1"); 
и так 15 раз (комбинаций) одна за другой 
И я наблюдаю что стек переполняется запросами

Comment: Не уверен, что понимаю, в чём задание и в чём проблема. Может, добавите пример во вторую часть вопроса или зададите новый вопрос с примером?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1227196/javascript-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb

Comment: Прежде чем разбираться со вторым вопросом. Мне не нравится, как у нас жёстко связаны имена переменных и вывод в консоль. Я добавил второй вариант функции, чтобы она стала универсальной. Так одна функция сможет работать с любым количеством чисел и с разными названиями ключей (бывших переменных). Если вам подойдёт, давайте заменим в вашем втором вопросе прежний вариант на новый. Так вы сможете сократить пример (не нужны будут несколько разных функций, нужны будут лишь разные вызовы одной). Возможно, тогда будет проще понять, чего вы пытаетесь добиться.